# I am stuck in this geometry problem

Tags: geometry, applications

Coordinates of point $P$ are $(4,5)$. If A and B are variable points on the straight lines $y=x$ and $y=2x$. Then the minimum value of ${ \left( PA+PB+AB \right)  }^{ 2 }$

I tried it as follow
PA will be minimum when when A is the foot of perpendicular from P to $y=x$ and similarly B is the foot of perpendicular from P to $y=2x$ . So I simply find all the distances by finding the coordinates of $A$ and $B$ .
But I am not confident in my approach as the $AB$ might not be minimum in this case .

Comment: If I am correct (I just minimized the sum of the distances using Wolfram Alpha to get the numerical result), the minimum does not occur when $A$ and $B$ are the foots of respective perpendicular lines. It occurs slightly below it, i.e. for $A\left(\frac{123}{28},\frac{123}{28}\right)$ and $B\left(\frac{41}{15},\frac{82}{15}\right).$

Comment: What did you get for the coordinates of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @dfnu I got somewhat different answers with a manual calculation using calculus.  I got $A=\left(\frac{168}{41},\frac{168}{41}\right),\ B=\left(\frac{101}{41},\frac{201}{41}\right)$  Checking it now.

Comment: @saulspatz yes I may definitely be wrong. I wonder if there's a way that does not use calculus at all.

Comment: @dfnu I just did it again using sympy, and got yet another answer.  I'll post it as an answer so you can check if I'm starting from the right equation.  My idea was to solve it using calculus, and then try to work backwards to an elementary solution.  I personally have no idea how to do it without calculus at this point.

Comment: @dfnu you found points A and B correctly using Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: @dfnu I corrected the mistake in my script, and now I agree with you.

Answer (score 6):

Let's reflect point $P (4,5)$ on lines $y = x$ and $y = 2x$.

Say reflection of point $P$ on line $y = x$ is point $A'$ and on line $y = 2x$ is $B'$. The distance between points $A'$ and $B'$ is the minimum distance you are looking for. This is simply because it will choose points $A$ and $B$ on the two lines in such a way that points $A', A, B, B'$ will be all collinear. This ensures $A'A (= PA) + AB + BB' (= PB)$ will be minimum.

Reflection of point P $(4,5)$ on line $y = x$ comes to $A' (5,4)$.

Reflection of point P $(4,5)$ on line $y = 2x$ comes to $B' (\frac{8}{5},\frac{31}{5})$.

So $(PA + PB + AB)^2 = (\frac{8}{5} - 5)^2 + (\frac{31}{5} - 4)^2 = \frac{82}{5}$

If you want to know points $A$ and $B$, equation of line $A'B'$ through two known points, $A'$ and $B'$, is $11x + 17y = 123$. It intersects two lines at $A (\frac{123}{28},\frac{123}{28})$ and $B (\frac{41}{15},\frac{82}{15})$.

Just added a rough diagram...

[image]

Comment: why this distance is minimum what is the logic behind that

Comment: Take point $A$ as an example. Say you choose A in a way that it is not on line $A'B'$. In that case points $A', A, B'$ will be a triangle so $A'A + AB' \gt A'B'$. Now $A'A = AP$ for all points on line $y = x$. So, $PA + AB' \gt A'B'$. When $A$ is on line $A'B'$, equality occurs and the sum is minimum. Same is true for point $B$.